# Can't install dotnet45 with winetricks on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine, winetricks, dotnet

I'm attempting to install .Net 4.5 with winetricks as described in 
https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25478&iTestingId=90239

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. I'm using Ubuntu Gnome as my desktop environment. I've searched extensively for a solution to this problem, but I can not find one.

I'm currently using wine-1.8, but I have the same issue with wine 1.7. 
Before I posted this I reset all my wine libraries.

```
# Remove wine related things
sudo apt-get remove wine-mono4.5.4
sudo apt-get remove playonlinux wine*
sudo apt-get remove winbind

# Do a fresh install of wine
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
#sudo apt-get install wine1.7
sudo apt-get install wine1.8
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
sudo apt-get install winbind

# Grab the latest winetricks
mkdir -p ~/tmp
cd ~/tmp
rm winetricks
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x ~/tmp/winetricks
```

I'm running the following procedure:

```
# Start fresh with a new wine directory
rm -rf $HOME/.wine32-dotnet45

# Make new WINEPREFIX 
export WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine32-dotnet45" 
export WINEARCH=win32
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine32-dotnet45" 
WINEARCH=win32

# Initial configuration of new wine prefix
wineboot -u

# Execute command to install dotnet45 as shown in documentation
~/tmp/winetricks -q dotnet45 corefonts
```

I've tried various versions of the above procedure (installing winbind, not installing winbind, wine1.7, wine1.8, with / without corefonts etc...). However, every time I run the last command I end up getting this error:

```
Note: command 'wine dotnetfx3.exe /q /c:install.exe /q' returned status 67.  Aborting.
```

I've googled for this error and tried many things to fix it, but I've come up with nothing. Hopefully someone here can help.

The output of the command is:

```
(venv)joncrall@Ooo:~/tmp$ ~/tmp/winetricks -q dotnet45 corefonts
Using winetricks 20160425 - sha1sum: ca54e3e664a0bffb0fc08e834900fdb58d067a9f with wine-1.8.0
Executing w_do_call dotnet45
Executing load_dotnet45
Executing w_do_call remove_mono
Executing load_remove_mono
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
DELETE - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4 (null) 0 0 1
Error: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value
Executing rm -f /home/joncrall/.wine32-dotnet45/dosdevices/c:/windows/system32/mscoree.dll
Executing w_do_call dotnet35
Executing load_dotnet35
------------------------------------------------------
dotnet35 does not yet fully work or install on wine.  Caveat emptor.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call remove_mono
Executing load_remove_mono
------------------------------------------------------
Mono does not appear to be installed.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call dotnet30sp1
Executing load_dotnet30sp1
Executing w_do_call remove_mono
Executing load_remove_mono
------------------------------------------------------
Mono does not appear to be installed.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call dotnet30
Executing load_dotnet30
Executing w_do_call remove_mono
Executing load_remove_mono
------------------------------------------------------
Mono does not appear to be installed.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call dotnet20
Executing load_dotnet20
Executing w_do_call remove_mono
Executing load_remove_mono
------------------------------------------------------
Mono does not appear to be installed.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call fontfix
Executing load_fontfix
Setting Windows version to win2k
Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit /S C:\windows\Temp\_dotnet20\set-winver.reg
------------------------------------------------------
Working around wine bug 34803 
------------------------------------------------------
DELETE - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\SBSDisabled (null) 0 0 1
Error: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value
Executing wine dotnetfx.exe /q /c:install.exe /q
fixme:advapi:DecryptFileA ("C:\\users\\joncrall\\Temp\\IXP000.TMP\\", 00000000): stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33f2f8,0x00000001,0x33f2e4) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:msi:ITERATE_DuplicateFiles We should track these duplicate files as well
fixme:imagehlp:BindImageEx (0, "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\cscomp.dll", "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\", (null), (nil)): stub
fixme:imagehlp:BindImageEx (0, "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\mscorsn.dll", "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\", (null), (nil)): stub
fixme:imagehlp:BindImageEx (0, "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\mscorwks.dll", "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\", (null), (nil)): stub
fixme:imagehlp:BindImageEx (0, "C:\\windows\\system32\\mscoree.dll", "C:\\windows\\system32\\", (null), (nil)): stub
fixme:imagehlp:BindImageEx (0, "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\mscorjit.dll", "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\", (null), (nil)): stub
fixme:imagehlp:BindImageEx (0, "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\mscorpe.dll", "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\", (null), (nil)): stub
fixme:imagehlp:BindImageEx (0, "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\vbc.exe", "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\", (null), (nil)): stub
fixme:imagehlp:BindImageEx (0, "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\diasymreader.dll", "C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\", (null), (nil)): stub
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {4e14fba2-2e22-11d1-9964-00c04fbbb345} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {4e14fba2-2e22-11d1-9964-00c04fbbb345} not registered
fixme:ole:CoGetClassObject CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {4e14fba2-2e22-11d1-9964-00c04fbbb345} could be created for context 0x15
fixme:mofcomp:wmain stub
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {a9e69610-b80d-11d0-b9b9-00a0c922e750} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {a9e69610-b80d-11d0-b9b9-00a0c922e750} not registered
fixme:ole:CoGetClassObject CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {a9e69610-b80d-11d0-b9b9-00a0c922e750} could be created for context 0x17
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {a9e69610-b80d-11d0-b9b9-00a0c922e750} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {a9e69610-b80d-11d0-b9b9-00a0c922e750} not registered
fixme:ole:CoGetClassObject CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {a9e69610-b80d-11d0-b9b9-00a0c922e750} could be created for context 0x17
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0"): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0001,0x400003f9,(nil),0x0002,0x00000000,0x33ecdc,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
fixme:loadperf:UnloadPerfCounterTextStringsW (L"u \"ASP.NET_2.0.50727\"", 1): stub
fixme:mofcomp:wmain stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33e880,0x000f0fff,0x33e8c0) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaStorePrivateData (0xcafe,0x33e8b4,(nil)) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:advapi:GetExplicitEntriesFromAclW 0x520190 0x33e7e8 0x33e7d4
fixme:loadperf:LoadPerfCounterTextStringsW (L"l \"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\aspnet_state_perf.ini\"", 1): stub
fixme:service:svcctl_ChangeServiceConfig2W SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS not implemented: period 86400 msg (null) cmd (null)
fixme:service:svcctl_ChangeServiceConfigW Setting password not supported
fixme:loadperf:LoadPerfCounterTextStringsW (L"l \"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\aspnet_perf.ini\"", 1): stub
fixme:loadperf:UnloadPerfCounterTextStringsW (L"u ASP.NET", 1): stub
fixme:loadperf:LoadPerfCounterTextStringsW (L"l \"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\aspnet_perf2.ini\"", 1): stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0"): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0002,0x0001,0x800003fc,(nil),0x0000,0x00000000,0x33ece4,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0"): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0001,0x400003fb,(nil),0x0002,0x00000000,0x33ecdc,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x6a2e3f5c) stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadStackGuarantee (0x33fc68): stub
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.EnterpriseServices"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System"
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {ecabb0c8-7f19-11d2-978e-0000f8757e2a} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {ecabb0c8-7f19-11d2-978e-0000f8757e2a} could be created for context 0x1
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {6eb22881-8a19-11d0-81b6-00a0c9231c29} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {6eb22881-8a19-11d0-81b6-00a0c9231c29} not registered
fixme:ole:CoGetClassObject CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {6eb22881-8a19-11d0-81b6-00a0c9231c29} could be created for context 0x15
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x60345090) stub
fixme:process:FlushProcessWriteBuffers : stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x1001da84) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x7a38d5c8) stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadStackGuarantee (0x33f000): stub
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from apartment threaded to multi-threaded
err:ole:CoGetContextToken apartment not initialised
err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData IMarshal::ReleaseMarshalData failed with error 0x8001011d
fixme:process:FlushProcessWriteBuffers : stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x790af2cc) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x7a38d5c8) stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadStackGuarantee (0x33ef44): stub
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from apartment threaded to multi-threaded
err:ole:CoGetContextToken apartment not initialised
fixme:process:FlushProcessWriteBuffers : stub
err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData IMarshal::ReleaseMarshalData failed with error 0x8001011d
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x64083a50) stub
fixme:service:svcctl_ChangeServiceConfig2W SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS not implemented: period 86400 msg (null) cmd (null)
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x64083a50) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x64083a50) stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadStackGuarantee (0x33f000): stub
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Drawing"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Windows.Forms"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Configuration"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Xml"
err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData IMarshal::ReleaseMarshalData failed with error 0x8001011d
fixme:process:FlushProcessWriteBuffers : stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x64208a74) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x7a38d5c8) stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadStackGuarantee (0x33ef44): stub
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Configuration"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Xml"
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from apartment threaded to multi-threaded
err:ole:CoGetContextToken apartment not initialised
fixme:process:FlushProcessWriteBuffers : stub
err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData IMarshal::ReleaseMarshalData failed with error 0x8001011d
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x64208a74) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x63fa7368) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x7a38d5c8) stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadStackGuarantee (0x33ef44): stub
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Drawing.Design"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Windows.Forms"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"Accessibility"
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from apartment threaded to multi-threaded
err:ole:CoGetContextToken apartment not initialised
fixme:process:FlushProcessWriteBuffers : stub
err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData IMarshal::ReleaseMarshalData failed with error 0x8001011d
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x64208a74) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x64083a50) stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadStackGuarantee (0x33f000): stub
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Security"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"Accessibility"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Configuration"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Xml"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Deployment"
err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData IMarshal::ReleaseMarshalData failed with error 0x8001011d
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from apartment threaded to multi-threaded
err:ole:CoGetContextToken apartment not initialised
fixme:process:FlushProcessWriteBuffers : stub
err:ole:CoReleaseMarshalData IMarshal::ReleaseMarshalData failed with error 0x8001011d
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x64208a74) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x7a38d5c8) stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadStackGuarantee (0x33ef44): stub
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Windows.Forms"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Security"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Xml"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"Accessibility"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Configuration"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap"
fixme:process:FlushProcessWriteBuffers : stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x64208a74) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x63fa7368) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x64083a50) stub
fixme:loadperf:LoadPerfCounterTextStringsW (L"C:\\windows\\system32\\lodctr.exe C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\_Networkingperfcounters.ini", 0): stub
fixme:loadperf:LoadPerfCounterTextStringsW (L"C:\\windows\\system32\\lodctr.exe C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\_DataOracleClientPerfCounters_shared12_neutral.ini", 0): stub
fixme:loadperf:LoadPerfCounterTextStringsW (L"C:\\windows\\system32\\lodctr.exe C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\_dataperfcounters_shared12_neutral.ini", 0): stub
fixme:loadperf:LoadPerfCounterTextStringsW (L"C:\\windows\\system32\\lodctr.exe C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\_DataPerfCounters.ini", 0): stub
fixme:loadperf:LoadPerfCounterTextStringsW (L"C:\\windows\\system32\\lodctr.exe C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\corperfmonsymbols.ini", 0): stub
Setting Windows version to winxp
Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit /S C:\windows\Temp\_dotnet20\set-winver.reg
------------------------------------------------------
Installing .net 3.0 runtime takes 3 minutes on a very fast machine, and the Finished dialog may hide in the taskbar.
------------------------------------------------------
Setting Windows version to winxp
Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit /S C:\windows\Temp\_dotnet30\set-winver.reg
Executing wine dotnetfx3.exe /q /c:install.exe /q
fixme:clusapi:GetNodeClusterState ((null),0x33ebf4) stub!
fixme:advapi:DecryptFileA ("c:\\43d72e875be0f81c93a29f98\\", 00000000): stub
fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity ((nil),-1,(nil),(nil),0,3,(nil),0,(nil)) - stub!
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33ef68,0x00000001,0x33ef60) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33e5f8,0x00000001,0x33e5e4) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:ngen:wmain stub: L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\ngen.exe" L"queue" L"pause"
fixme:mountmgr:harddisk_ioctl Unsupported ioctl 2d0c00 (device=2d access=0 func=300 method=0)
fixme:cdrom:CDROM_GetMediaType : faking success
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33dd68,0x00000001,0x33dd54) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:msi:MsiGetFeatureValidStatesW 1 L"WAP_1.0_Core" 0x33aae4 stub returning 8
fixme:msi:MsiGetFeatureValidStatesW 1 L"Servicing_Key" 0x33aae4 stub returning 8
fixme:cdrom:CDROM_GetMediaType : faking success
fixme:ngen:wmain stub: L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\ngen.exe" L"queue" L"pause"
fixme:ngen:wmain stub: L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\ngen.exe" L"queue" L"pause"
fixme:clusapi:GetNodeClusterState ((null),0x33ebf4) stub!
fixme:advapi:DecryptFileA ("c:\\d11680f21c83bfdf97b0\\", 00000000): stub
fixme:setupapi:pSetupGetGlobalFlags stub
fixme:wintrust:WinVerifyTrust unimplemented for 4
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {acadf079-cbcd-4032-83f2-fa47c4db096f} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {acadf079-cbcd-4032-83f2-fa47c4db096f} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:msg:pack_message msg 14 (WM_ERASEBKGND) not supported yet
fixme:sfc:SFC_3 0
fixme:wintrust:CryptCATGetCatAttrInfo 0x1bdec8, L"SPAttr"
fixme:wintrust:CryptCATGetCatAttrInfo 0x1bdec8, L"SPLevel"
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW (0x10182d6, 0x1099138, {aefe45f4-8548-42b4-b1c8-25673b07ad8b}, 1, 0x33fd10, (null), (null), 0x1099140): stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {aefe45f4-8548-42b4-b1c8-25673b07ad8b}
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"Microsoft-Windows-SpoolerFilterPipelineSVC"): stub
fixme:psdrv:PSDRV_UpdateDevCaps Can't find page
fixme:psdrv:PSDRV_UpdateDevCaps Can't find page
fixme:winspool:AddPrintProcessorW ((null),L"Windows NT x86",L"filterpipelineprintproc.dll",L"MS_XPS"): stub
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids deadbeef: stub
fixme:setupapi:pSetupGetGlobalFlags stub
fixme:setupapi:pSetupGetGlobalFlags stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceA ((null),"NtServicePack"): stub
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW (L"",L"NtServicePack"): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventA (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x400e1119,0x464d20,0x0002,0x00000000,0x33bc88,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x400e1119,0x464d20,0x0002,0x00000000,0x147880,(nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
fixme:ngen:wmain stub: L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\ngen.exe" L"queue" L"pause"
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33d098,0x00000001,0x33d084) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33d098,0x00000001,0x33d084) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadStackGuarantee (0x33fc68): stub
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.ServiceModel.Install"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"Microsoft.Web.Administration"
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x60345090) stub
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.ServiceProcess"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Web"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Xml"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.Configuration"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.ServiceModel.Install.XmlSerializers"
fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW (L".",L"System.ServiceModel.Install 3.0.0.0"): stub
fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0001,0x0000,0x00000000,(nil),0x0001,0x00000000,0x93f8d0,0x93f778): stub
err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'latex'  Key being added: 'latex'\r\n   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)\r\n   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(Object key, Object value)\r\n   at System.Collections.Specialized."...
fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
fixme:process:FlushProcessWriteBuffers : stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x5e40072c) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x7a38d5c8) stub
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"DD_CA_InstallXwsRegExe_X86.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8" returned 1603
fixme:thread:SetThreadStackGuarantee (0x33fc68): stub
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.ServiceModel.Install"
fixme:shell:URL_ParseUrl failed to parse L"System.ServiceModel.Install.XmlSerializers"
err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'latex'  Key being added: 'latex'\r\n   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)\r\n   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Add(Object key, Object value)\r\n   at System.Collections.Specialized."...
fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
fixme:process:FlushProcessWriteBuffers : stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x5e40072c) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x7a38d5c8) stub
fixme:ngen:wmain stub: L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\ngen.exe" L"queue" L"pause"
fixme:ngen:wmain stub: L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\ngen.exe" L"queue" L"pause"
fixme:ngen:wmain stub: L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\ngen.exe" L"queue" L"pause"
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33d098,0x00000001,0x33d084) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:ngen:wmain stub: L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\ngen.exe" L"queue" L"pause"
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33d098,0x00000001,0x33d084) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:ngen:wmain stub: L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\ngen.exe" L"queue" L"pause"
fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x33d098,0x00000001,0x33d084) stub
fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
fixme:ngen:wmain stub: L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\ngen.exe" L"queue" L"pause"
fixme:ngen:wmain stub: L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\ngen.exe" L"queue" L"pause"
fixme:ngen:wmain stub: L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\ngen.exe" L"queue" L"continue"
------------------------------------------------------
Note: command 'wine dotnetfx3.exe /q /c:install.exe /q' returned status 67.  Aborting.
------------------------------------------------------
```

I removed some of the redundant parts to get within the character limit, but anything important in there should still be visible.

The full output is in this pastebin http://pastebin.com/nwcLW2vY

Furthermore, if I rerun the command I get this error:

```
(venv)joncrall@Ooo:~/tmp$     ~/tmp/winetricks -q dotnet45 corefonts
Using winetricks 20160425 - sha1sum: ca54e3e664a0bffb0fc08e834900fdb58d067a9f with wine-1.8.0
Executing w_do_call dotnet45
------------------------------------------------------
error: dotnet45 conflicts with dotnet20, which is already installed.
------------------------------------------------------
```

so I have to blow away my entire WINEPREFIX every time I try something new.

Comment: [Looking at this bugreport](https://code.google.com/archive/p/winetricks/issues/205) and the [link to this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/41656/266507), try to execute `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`, repeat the installation again, and tell if it worked.

Comment: I have looked at that link before. I tried again, but it returned the same error. That particular issue is from 2012. I don't believe it is related to what I'm seeing.

Comment: «That particular issue» is still relevant *(as you can find if you peek at the current value of the ptrace_scope)* because it is not, actually, a bug. I.e. it is a bug, but rather in .net installer trying to spy on processes for no reason. Anyway, I think I'd probably try to download the latest .net by hand, run it in Wine, and if it won't install either, [consider reporting a bug](https://wiki.winehq.org/Bugs) — it is still the work of Wine, to make workarounds, getting apps work. And btw, why not just use wine-mono instead?

Comment: Also try the latest Wine-staging: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging`

Comment: i followed the steps you give above, and seem to have successfully installed wine w/ dotnet45. cheers

Answer (score 5):

Do this. It configures a new wine 32bit prefix and installs it.

```
env WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winetricks dotnet45
```