# How to install Microsoft PowerBI with Wine

Tags: software-installation, wine, microsoft, office365

While installing PBIDesktop_x64.msi using Wine, I am getting installation Failed Msg, i.e.:

```
 MS PowerBI Desktop (x64) requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 or later.
```

Please see the Error Msg in the attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/783211/cant-install-dotnet45-with-winetricks-on-ubuntu-14-04 or https://askubuntu.com/questions/881435/problem-to-install-net-4-6-using-wine

Comment: I Think you mut install .NET Framework 4.5 previously... https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/system-requirements Good luck...

Comment: Any progress on this? I managed to install .NET Framework 4.5 as mentioned, but the installer crashes for me after clicking next.

Comment: @run-out  That page is for Power BI _Report Server_

Answer (score 2):

As of now (Wine 8.x) Microsoft Power BI Desktop can't run in Wine, even if you could get .NET runtimes installed.  Since it's a Microsoft application of significant complexity that is unlikely to change soon, but who knows.

If someone arrives here wanting to know how to have .NET framework support in wine, obtain the installer for "Wine Mono" from the wine website, using the version appropriate for your Wine installation (or earlier).

You can also obtain a more recent .NET runtime installer direct from Microsoft (or via winetricks), but this may or may not work.  I did both in my main wine prefix and it works fine (with other .NET apps, I mean), and so I'm not going to touch it further.  I used a .NET runtime version 7.0.5.

But to repeat, you can't use this to run Power BI in Wine.

*Update* - since I wrote this answer I have been running Power BI in a Virtualbox virtual machine.  It's not the best experience in the world but it's usable.