# Monodevelop fails to connect debugger when not running as sudo

Tags: permissions, 18.04, kde, monodevelop

I am using monodevelop with Ubuntu 18.04 and using KDE desktop. When I start monodevelop as sudo all is working fine. When I start it normally without sudo then it fails to connect to the debugger when trying to debug an application.
Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: See if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/41656/266507) helps.

Comment: nope... it did not work with me